# Options for generating create scripts for all objects in Oracle schema

Tags: sql, oracle, continuous-integration, oracle11g

I have several schemas in Oracle that must be promoted through dev, test, staging and production environments.

I need a command line tool that can take a script based snapshot of the dev environment (generate create scripts for a schema and all of its child objects which include OWB mappings and workflows).

**What options exist that can be triggered from the command line and will generate create scripts suitable for inclusion in a source control system?** The command line functionality is significant because the process will be triggered by a CI server (TeamCity).

Comment: To be clear, are you looking for a script that contains just the changes to objects, or a script containing ALL the objects?

Comment: @cagcowboy At the moment, no change monitor is needed. My use of RG's schema compare was just a comparison of an active, populated dev schema against an empty schema. Just something capable of creating a script that can create all objects in a new (empty) schema and in the right sequence for dependencies, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Check out the in-built DBMS_METADATA package.

Lots of examples of usage on stackoverflow (or just google)

Answer (score 1):

While much of the table structures etc can be mapped across using a variety of tools - your OWB mappings cannot be simply copied into a new environment  - they must be properly deployed using either the OWB GUI or an OMB+ script to a new environment in order to have them properly registered into the runtime repository. And how you do that will depend on how you have the repositories configured.

I had posted an OMB+ script to deploy to a clean environment [on the Oracle message boards](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2410921�) a couple of years back. OWB has progressed a version or two since - but it might provide you with a starting point for that aspect of things.

Answer (score 0):

Use expdp to dump the schema, and impdp with the SQLFILE option to generate a file of SQL commands to re-create the objects.